# binary file editing using python script

Tags: python

I want to do some operation on binary file using python script.
I have one binary file. And I want to append binary data to it.

Example:
File `abc.bin` is available.

Command:

> python file_append.py abc.bin 1234 5678

I want to append "1234" and "5678" at the end of the binary file `abc.bin`.

So I opened the file with "ab" mode (append + binary).
When I append a command line argument, it appends the ASCII value of the argument.

How can I append the hex value (here 1234 and 5678) at the end of the file?

Code:

```
fo = open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'ab')
fv = string.atoi(sys.argv[2])
ft = string.atoi(sys.argv[3])
fo.write(fv)
```

Comment: so you want to append 4 bytes with hexa values 12, 34, 56, and 78?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to parse the command line arguments, split them into two-digit groups, interpret then these numbers as ASCII hexa codes and append this at the end of the binary file of interest, then you could do something like this

```
of = open(sys.argv[1], 'ab')
for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    val = int(arg)
    for b in (val/100, val%100):
        of.write(chr(int(str(b), base=16)))
```

`python file_append.py abc.bin 1234 5678` then produces file `abc.bin` the content of which can be checked with `hexdump -C abc.bin` which shows

```
00000000  12 34 56 78                                       |.4Vx|
00000004
```

Comment: This won't cope with data containing hex digits > 9.

Comment: that it won't, I was assuming (perhaps mistakenly) that the input is expected to be a decimal integer...

Comment: Fair enough. But in that case, your code is still wrong, because it interprets '1234' as 0x1234 instead of 0x04d2.

Comment: as far as I can tell, it gives the same output as the approach using `a2b_hex` so it seems that it does what was desired (for input containing only decimal digits)...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the code below.

```
fo = open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'ab')
f1 = binascii.a2b_hex(sys.argv[2])
fo.write(f1)
f2 = binascii.a2b_hex(sys.argv[3])
fo.write(f2)
fo.close()
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You could join the data strings into one string & pass that to `a2b_hex`, rather than converting & writing each separately. And then your program could cope with any number of data strings. Eg, `binascii.a2b_hex(''.join(sys.argv[2:]))`